# How to display last 18 week data in snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to display last 18 week data dynamically in snowflake cloud platform query.
Can someone help how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Tejas

I tried Dateadd function but it did not work.

Comment: You should start by posting what you've tried and even better an example of input/output expected.

Comment: what did you try with dateadd exactly? It should work like ```select * from my_table where date_column between dateadd(week, -18, current_timestamp()) and current_timestamp()```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aek. I will definitely try this solution and keep you posted.

Comment: When you say you "tried Dateadd" - how did you try it?  I'm wondering if you are using it correctly. One common mistake is, did you make sure the argument is negative to go backwards 18 weeks?  DATEADD(WEEK, -18, CURRENT_DATE)

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks a lot! Actually earlier I was subtracting 91 days. But this approach looks good to me. I will try implementing and keep you posted.